# No response from varnish docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm tying to run varnish on [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock).
I took varnish configuration from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/varnish).

The problem is that there is no even 503 error and no logs in the varnish log. 
80 port is only for varnish (nginx container is deaktivated off for test).
If nginx container is activated on port 80 then i can reach website without problem.

Does any have an idea why varnish container is not reachable at all? And what is the next step to make research there?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM varnish:6.3

# Set Environment Variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install Dependencies
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils && apt-get upgrade -y
#RUN mkdir /home/site && mkdir /home/site/cache
#RUN apt-get install -y varnish
#RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Setting Configurations
ENV VARNISH_CONFIG  /etc/varnish/default.vcl
ENV CACHE_SIZE      128m
ENV VARNISHD_PARAMS -p default_ttl=3600 -p default_grace=3600
ENV VARNISH_PORT    6081
ENV BACKEND_HOST    localhost
ENV BACKEND_PORT    80

COPY default.vcl /etc/varnish/default.vcl
COPY start.sh /etc/varnish/start.sh

RUN chmod +x /etc/varnish/start.sh

CMD ["/etc/varnish/start.sh"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

default.vcl:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
  .host = "8080";
  .port = "localhost"; // tried 127.0.0.1, workspace, server IP.
}
```

start.sh:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

for name in BACKEND_PORT BACKEND_HOST VARNISH_SERVER
do
    eval value=\$$name
    sed -i "s|\${${name}}|${value}|g" /etc/varnish/default.vcl
done

echo "exec varnishd \
    -a :$VARNISH_PORT \
    -T 127.0.0.1:6082 \
    -F \
    -f $VARNISH_CONFIG \
    -s malloc,$CACHE_SIZE \
    $VARNISHD_PARAMS"

exec bash -c \
    "exec varnishd \
    -a :$VARNISH_PORT \
    -T 127.0.0.1:6082 \
    -F \
    -f $VARNISH_CONFIG \
    -s malloc,$CACHE_SIZE \
    $VARNISHD_PARAMS"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  percona:
    driver: local

services:

  ### Workspace Utilities ##################################
  workspace:
    container_name: workspace
    build:
      context: ./workspace
      args:
        - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=7.2
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
    tty: true
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    links:
      - docker-in-docker

  ### NGINX Server #########################################
  nginx:
    container_name: Nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      args:
        - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
        - VARNISH_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${VARNISH_PROXY1_BACKEND_HOST}
        - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
        - VARNISH_UPSTREAM_PORT=80
        - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
      - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
      - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
      - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  ### Varnish ##########################################
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build: ./varnish
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      - VARNISH_CONFIG="/etc/varnish/default.vcl"
      - CACHE_SIZE=128m
      - VARNISHD_PARAMS="-p default_ttl=3600 -p default_grace=3600"
      - VARNISH_PORT=80
      - BACKEND_HOST=workspace
      - BACKEND_PORT=8888
      - VARNISH_SERVER=SERVER1
    links:
      - workspace
    networks:
      - frontend

  ### Docker-in-Docker ################################################
  docker-in-docker:
    container_name: docker-in-docker
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    expose:
      - 2375
    networks:
      - backend
```

Container is up and running:
[image: container log]
Docker ps output:
[image: docker ps]

Comment: It seems you have not published ports - show how you are launching container. Show your compose file.

Comment: Also, in a container, it's best to bind to all addresses, since you don't know what you're going to get. So where you're specifying it should listen on 127.0.0.1:6082 ,see if you can set it to 0.0.0.0:6082. Secondarily, make sure those ports are exposed when docker runs

Comment: Also, in your vcl file, are host and port backwards? I'm not familiar with varnish, but I would put host as '0.0.0.0' and port as 8080

Comment: @michalk as i mentioned in the question, i tried nginx on 80 port and it works fine then. I updated question with the composer file.

Comment: @Dockstar thx for the reply. I tried that, varnish says then: "VCL compilation failed" because of 0.0.0.0 in the configuration. I'm just thinking how to check if this port accessible..

Comment: This is because you actually publish ports for your `nginnx` and you do not do it for your `varnish` service. If you want to reach `proxy` service from host you should also publish ports. `expose` does not publish ports - it is only for documentation purposes.

Comment: @michalk you are right. it works!  I had no port section in the compose file.  can you post your last comment please? i will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you actually publish ports for your `nginx` and you do not do it for your varnish service. If you want to reach `proxy` service from host you should also publish ports. `expose` does not publish ports - it is only for documentation purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Solution was to add `ports:
        - "${VARNISH_PORT}:80"`